# Android Studio Library reference ..\OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk\sdk\java could not be found

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-studio

I am trying to import an Android Project which was build on Eclipse to Android Studio. The project is also using OpenCV Library.

I am facing an error as the below.

I am not sure how to solve it. I am new to Android Programming. The project was take from https://github.com/ayuso2013/face-recognition

```
 * Project face-recognition:C:\Users\bdulrahe\AndroidStudioProjects\face-recognition-master\project.properties:
Library reference ..\OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk\sdk\java could not be found
Path is C:\Users\bdulrahe\AndroidStudioProjects\face-recognition-master\..\OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk\sdk\java which resolves to C:\Users\bdulrahe\AndroidStudioProjects\OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk\sdk\java
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the version 2.4.9 SDK instead from here : http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/

Import in eclipses, reference in the face-recognition project. It will work.